# Cannot get correct syntax for index value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following php table and js function I've been working on. The problem is, the index ($ind) works correctly in the php, but I cannot figure out the syntax in the js function.  The output of var ind= $('id')[ind]; is undefined. When I substitute and set var ind= ; it gives me the last index value in the array for each item. What can I set var ind equal to to capture the $ind value of the php in javascript?

```
    <table id="manage-items" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <thead>
        <tr class="search">
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th><?php echo $this->translate('Quantity');?></th>
          <th><?php echo $this->translate('Status'); ?></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <?php $ind = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) {
    $item_link = 'type=product';
    ?>

      <div id="item_<?php echo $ind; ?>" style="display:none;">

        <tr id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>

          <td class="Quantity">
            <?php if ($item->item_quantity) { ?>
            <span class="silvertext"><?php echo $item->item_quantity; ?></span>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <span class="silvertext">0</span>
            <?php } ?>
          </td>

          <td class="Status">

            <?php if (in_array($item['active'], array(0, 1))) { ?>
            <div class="switch">

              <label for="active[<?php echo $ind; ?>]"
                     class="switch-label switch-label-off">Active</label>
              <input type="radio" class="switch-input"
                     id="active[<?php echo $ind; ?>]"
                     name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]"
                     value="1" <?php if ($item['active'] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?>>

              <label for="inactive[<?php echo $ind; ?>]"
                     class="switch-label switch-label-on">Inactive</label>
              <input type="radio" class="switch-input"
                     id="inactive[<?php echo $ind; ?>]"
                     name="item[<?php echo $ind; ?>][status]"
                     value="0" <?php if ($item['active'] == 0) echo 'checked'; ?>>

              <span class="switch-selection"></span>
            </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <?php echo $item['active']; ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $ind++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

        if (typeof ind == "undefined") {
          ind = 0;
        }
        $('input[type="radio"]').live('change', function () {
          var status = this.value;
          var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
          var quantity = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Quantity > span").text();
          var ind= $('id')[ind];

          // a bunch of other javascript

        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML source code (php output)? Have you checked the console?

Comment: @Daidon, there are no errors in the console but the output of var ind= $('id')[ind];   is undefined.  When I substitute and set var ind= <?php echo $ind; ?>;  it gives me the last index value in the array for each item.

Comment: try typeof ind === (three equals)

Comment: @Daidon sorry, that didn't help.

Comment: And put a var before ind in the if clause

Comment: @Daidon My new if clause then reads: if (typeof var ind === "undefined") {.  That creates an error in the console - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129856/discussion-between-daidon-and-ian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var id contains the ID of the tr you want to access.

if you iterate through id with .find, you can access the span that you want to change.

```
var target = $("#"+id).find('span')[5];
```

Apply changes then on target

```
$(target).css("...", "...");
```

Comment: that didn't work.  no console errors but the var ind equals the last value for each loop.  I note that var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); gives the correct id for each record. Is there a way to grab the index value with reference to the id?

Comment: I would like to ask you for some actual html code, so i can see what the mistake could be. At the moment, i dont even know what exactly you are trying to select with $('id') . Do you have id-tags in the html?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by what you need. From the html above, I get var id from the following html line, <tr id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>">.  If it is easier, I can paste the whole page but the essentials are above, as far as I know.

Comment: It would be nice if you could call the website so the php code gets executed and copy the client side html code in addition to your already given php source code

Comment: Changed the answer :-)